# Can no longer access "Apps" section

Tags: google-fabric

I can no longer access the Apps section of Fabric's Settings page. The Apps page is where we can upload missing dSYMs, for example.

Has the Apps functionality moved, or is there something we need to do to regain access?

[image: Apps grayed out]

Answer (score 2):

Paul from Fabric here. We're looking into an intermittent glitch with the Apps button, but you should be able to still access your apps here: https://fabric.io/settings/apps.